# How to design http stress testerin Java

Tags: java, multithreading, http, asynchronous, threadpool

I would like to run as many requests as possible against a URL and would like to know what the best approach would be.

Requirements trigger GET requests and read response.

I started by simply creating a runnable that synchronously does a get and blocks. Then I dumped those with a loop into a fixed thread pool executor. Running it with 100 Threads will result in 200 requests per second.

I also looked into async libraries like http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-4.0.x/ but running those will result in lots of futures that never return.

Can things like NIO or async libraries help to improve throughput or how should I tackle the problem?

Comment: Have you had a look at jmeter?

Answer (score 1):

There is a free and open source tool from Apache called [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/). It's designed for HTTP load testing and provides

- record-and-replay capabilities via embedded [HTTP Proxy Server](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-superpower-http-proxy-server) for rapid tests development
- [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) - to assure that response time does not exceed reasonable values, check response content, return code, message, etc.
- [Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) - to build tables and graphs which help to analyze load test results.
- Already has a number of [plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/) which extend base functionality
- Supports scripting using a number of supported languages like JavaScript or [Beanshell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

Hope this helps you in your testing and saves your valuable time from re-inventing the wheel to produce a better product instead.

Comment: I know about JMeter but I am really more interessted in the design behind it. Have can JMeter create more load with the same base libraries. How does it handle threads and IO.